# Multiple instances of a WinForms application on one Windows system

Tags: c#, .net, multiprocessing, virtual-machine

I have a complex legacy software which is a C# WinForms application, recently upgraded to .NET Framework 4.7.2 and added with a WCF REST API for external communication.

This application requires certain files on the disk, certain partitions needs to be available (such as a D: drive) and so forth (due to a lot of hardcoded file management etc). The app also requires a license USB dongle and a big SDK framework installed on the PC.

Now we would like to run several instances of this application in one server and get results out from it via its REST API. Is there any way we can do this? I guess several virtual machines would work, but is there any other way, Docker maybe?

Comment: Docker doesn't simulate a full physical system, and when you start saying "partitions" and "required physical devices" that's not something Docker can provide.

Comment: Reboot it. Sounds like you are in a cul-de-sac (dead end street).

Comment: Reboot what? Rewrite the app? Its not in our budget and its not feasible at this point.

Comment: By default, you can open and run several instances of the winforms application in the same server, but I guess that is not exactly what you are after?

Comment: @insane_developer thats right, since each instance requires file management on the drive etc. And to access the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is out. As a commenter stated, Docker is not designed to mimic real hardware. See [this comparison](https://www.upguard.com/blog/docker-vs-vmware-how-do-they-stack-up) for more information.

I suggest a traditional Windows virtual machine and something like [Hyper-V USB Passthrough](https://www.net-usb.com/virtual-usb/hyperv-usb-passthrough/).